# Google Earth Engine: cannot read "undefined" of undefined

Tags: error, google-earth-engine

Yesterday I was able to run the next code but today is giving me an error such as: **"cannot read "undefined" of undefined"**

```js
//Choose country using GEE Feature Collection
var region = geometry;


// Collect data and filter by total dates
var modisNDVI = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/MOD13Q1');

print(modisNDVI)

// Image collections for NDVI for all years, one value per month.
// Here is where you can change the dates.
var collection05 = ee.ImageCollection(modisNDVI.filterDate('2002-01-01', '2016-12-31'));
var collection01 = ee.ImageCollection(modisNDVI.filterDate('2008-01-01', '2008-12-31'));

//Clip to Specified Region
var clipped05 = collection05.mean().clip(region)
var clipped01 = collection01.mean().clip(region)

// Charts //
//Long-Term Time Series
var TS5 = Chart.image.seriesByRegion(collection05, small_region,  ee.Reducer.mean(),'NDVI', 500, 'system:time_start').setOptions({
          title: 'NDVI Long-Term Time Series',
          vAxis: {title: 'NDVI'},
});
print(TS5);

//Short-Term Time Series
var TS1 = Chart.image.seriesByRegion(collection01, small_region,  ee.Reducer.mean(),'NDVI', 500, 'system:time_start').setOptions({
          title: 'NDVI Short-Term Time Series',
          vAxis: {title: 'NDVI'},
});
print(TS1);

var mult05 = clipped05.multiply(0.0001)
var mult01 = clipped01.multiply(0.0001)

//Set Center of Map & Add Clipped Image Layer
Map.setCenter(-50, -10, 3); //long, lat, zoom
Map.addLayer (mult05.select('NDVI'))
Map.addLayer (mult01.select('NDVI'));

// Create a geometry representing an export region.
var roi = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
    [[[-68.675537109375,-16.799282416303967],
      [-68.79638671875,-17.45023229881414],
      [-68.291015625,-17.539296556236692],
      [-68.126220703125,-16.92019465044387],
      [-68.675537109375,-16.799282416303967]]]);
// Export the image, specifying scale and region.
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: clipped01,
  description: 'NDVI_MODIS_2008',
  scale: 250,
  region: roi
});
```

Does anyone know where is the mistake? It can be a server issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collection `MODIS/MOD13Q1` seems to be unreachable. Try:

```js
// Collect data and filter by total dates
var modisNDVI = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD13Q1');
```

Works for me. For more information about the reasons of being unreachable you should ask in GEE Developers forum (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-earth-engine-developers)